# Should it be faster to create a Polars dataframe from a file than from an object in memory?

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I'm creating a Polars dataframe out of several million rows from a Clickhouse database. I'm using the Clickhouse Python driver to pull the data (specifically the stream rows function), so what I get in return is a tuple of values from each row, which I then dump into a list. I was loading that list into Polars afterwards, but I noticed it took a while so as an experiment, I tried saving it to a CSV file first and then loading it into Polars. I timed both versions and the CSV loading version is more than 2x faster (2.5 minutes versus 6.65 minutes). Is this expected?

Notes:

- Windows machine, i7 CPU, 32 GB RAM
- I had looked at using ConnectorX instead, but I'm running Python 3.12 and I don't want to downgrade.

Here's the CSV-loading version of the code:

```
class Clickhouse(Common):
    def __init__(self, columns, table, where=None, group_by=None, order_by=None):
        super().__init__(columns, table, where, group_by=group_by, order_by=order_by)
        self.client = self.create_client()
        self.query = self.create_query()

    def get_results(self):
        rows = self._run_query()

        with open('./data/ch_raw.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(self.columns)
            writer.writerows(rows)


        df = polars.read_csv('./data/ch_raw.csv', dtypes={'inventory_ssp_id': polars.String})
        df = df.with_columns(polars.col('ts').str.strptime(dtype=polars.Datetime, strict=False))
        df = df.with_columns(polars.col('ts').alias('date').cast(polars.Date))
        df = df.drop('ts')
        df = df.rename({'imps': 'impressions', 'ssp_price': 'revenue'})
        df = df.select(
            ['date', 'advertiser', 'inventory_ssp_id', 'placement_id', 'platform_id', 'ad_height', 'ad_width',
             'country_id', 'impressions', 'revenue']
        )
        df = df.group_by(df.columns[:-2]).sum()

        return df

    def _run_query(self):
        rows = []

        with self.client.query_rows_stream(self.query) as stream:
            for i, row in enumerate(stream):
                rows.append(row)

                if i % 10000000 == 0:
                    print(f'Collecting row {i}...')

        return rows
```

Comment: I believe it is expected, yes - and parquet should be faster than csv. There have been a few tickets on github with regards to the performance of injesting data from lists/tuples e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14742

Comment: Thanks @jqurious, I'll follow that ticket you linked. If you can post that as the answer, I will accept it.